# MYSQL how to declare a datetime variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

My code:

```
DECLARE report_date DATETIME;
set report_date='2013-01-17 00:00:00';

SELECT  *
  FROM `NMPP`.`capacitypersecond` 
  WHERE `StreamDT` >=report_date and `StreamDT` < '2013-01-18 00:00:00'  ;

SELECT  *
  FROM `NMPP`.`capacityperHr` 
  WHERE `StreamDT` >=report_date and `StreamDT` < '2013-01-18 00:00:00'  ;

SELECT  *
  FROM `NMPP`.`capacityperDay` 
  WHERE `TJLDate` >=report_date and `TJLDate` < '2013-01-18 00:00:00'  ;
```

-

```
DECLARE report_date DATETIME;
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE report_date DATETIME' at line 1 */
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 5 queries: 0.000 sec. */
```

Comment: Is this inside a `BEGIN`/`END` statement? Because that's the only place where `DECLARE` is legal.

Comment: Could you provide more information? What version of MySQL are you using, are you declaring this inside a stored procedure, etc.?

Comment: @Jon not in begin/end, then how to declare it in a sql file?

Comment: Then you have to set it like `set @report_date:='2013-01-17 00:00:00';` then use it in the query like `@report_date`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

get rid of `declare`:

```
set @report_date = '2013-01-17 00:00:00';

SELECT  *
  FROM `NMPP`.`capacitypersecond` 
  WHERE `StreamDT` >= @report_date and `StreamDT` < '2013-01-18 00:00:00'  ;
```

Comment: Yes and refer to your variable with @ like `@report_date ` in query

Comment: -1. Yes why should we get rid of DECLARE ? the way you solved it is by using user defined variables ignoring the proper way to declare a variable as DATETIME.

Comment: @Ehsan because op says the code is not inside begin/end block in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If so then the proper answer is to define a begin/end block to wrap the DECLARE statement. The  problem with user defined variables is that they are loosely typed and stay out of the scope of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 19):

or with cast:

```
set @report_date = cast('2013-01-17 00:00:00' as datetime);
```

Comment: Yes and refer to your variable with @ like `@report_date ` in query

Answer (score 1):

All the DECLARE should be at the start of the trigger,stored procedure.

This is not a C++ like language where you can mix declarations and statements, but more like C, where all declarations must be done before all statements.

Comment: True, but it isn't relevant to the question because putting at the top a declaration of type DATETIME does not work.